# Error: Unable to export features with empty geometry

Tags: google-earth-engine

Hopefully a simple question.

I'm concatenating some fields in a featureCollection by running this .map function:

```
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('users/xxx/featurecollection')
    .map(function (feature) {      
        return feature.set('combined', 
          feature.getString('ColA')
          .cat(' ')
          .cat(feature.getString('ColB'))
          .cat(' ')
          .cat(feature.getString('ColC'))
          );      
    });
```

It works fine.  But, when I go to export to an Asset, I get the error "**Error: Unable to export features with empty geometry**"

```
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: fc,
  description:'exportToTableAssetExample',
  assetId: 'MyExportedFC',
});
```

Question:  How do I skip features with Null/empty geometry in the above .map function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ee.Filter.bounds()` drops features without a geometry. If you first construct a bounded geometry of all features, you could use this filter like this:

```
// bounded geometry
var bounded = fc.geometry().bounds();

// filter the feature without a geometry
var filtered = fc.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(bounded))
```

[Example link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/448d454783529401a5bfc2a80743cc19). Alternatively, use `fc.filterBounds()`.